# kotlin reflection for java method accepting null Class array

Tags: java, android, reflection, kotlin

I have java code like this:

```
Method m = device.getClass()
        .getMethod("removeBondNative", (Class[]) null);
m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
```

and I am trying to write the same thing in Kotlin like this:

```
device.javaClass.getMethod("removeBondNative", null as Class<*>).invoke(device, null as Any)
```

but I get this error message:

```
Process: com.example.zemcd.toofxchange, PID: 17466
   kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.Class<*>
       at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.BluetoothUtils$Companion.unPair(BluetoothUtils.kt:61)
       at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.DeviceAdapter$DeviceHolder$bindItems$1$$special$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.onClick(DeviceAdapter.kt:98)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21349)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

I also tried changing null to Unit:

```
device.javaClass.getMethod("removeBondNative", Unit as Class<*>).invoke(device, null as Any)
```

but still encounter error:

```
Process: com.example.zemcd.toofxchange, PID: 19219
   java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
       at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.BluetoothUtils$Companion.unPair(BluetoothUtils.kt:61)
       at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.DeviceAdapter$DeviceHolder$bindItems$1$$special$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.onClick(DeviceAdapter.kt:98)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21349)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

What I am doing wrong here? how can java reflection be mirrored in Kotlin in a situation like this?

Comment: What is the type of the parameter of `removeBondNative`? Usually you giving the class of the parameter there like for example `Int::class.java`. Why are you casting null to Class here?

Comment: @Phoca the param type is possibly Boolean but the examples I have been finding all implement with null Class array. I have seen posts that claim it works for them but for me not at all. I will try to change to Boolean but as for the call to invoke how can I know what to pass as argument? I am trying to unpair a Bluetooth device if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you the problem: `Class<*>` is a non-null type, so casts to it always check the casted value isn't null. You could write `null as Class<*>?`, but that would be equivalent of `(Class) null`. You want `null as Array<Class<*>>?` instead.

However, at any rate this seems pointless: ["If parameterTypes is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) so `.getMethod("removeBondNative")` should give you the same result.

Comment: What ended up working in the end was going back to using removeBond as in: `device::Class.java.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(device)` omitting the parameter list altogether.